# How can I measure the speed/performance of a program?

Tags: benchmark

Recently, I was looking at the performance impact of tools such as `strace`. For instance, this [blog post](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-11/strace-wow-much-syscall.html) uses the default metrics given by dd.

I wanted to do some measurements myself but with other programs. Is there a tool that measures the speed of execution of an arbitrary program?

Comment: The very first step is to precisely specify what *exactly* you mean by "performance". E.g. are you talking about throughput, latency, jitter, something else? Cold-start, warm-start or steady-state? After you have decided *what* exactly you want to measure, you have to create a benchmark. Note that creating benchmarks that actually reliably measure what you want them to measure is very hard. Even benchmarking engineers that do nothing but writing benchmarks all day frequently get it wrong. (A famous example is SpecJVM98_209_db which is supposed to test database performance but actually spends …

Comment: … 80% of its execution time sorting strings, and thus tests the performance of the `String` class.) Then, when you have benchmark that reliably, repeatedly measures what you want to measure, you have to ensure that there are no environmental influences on the thing you are measuring. E.g. make sure there are no other processes running in your system that may impact the measurement, make sure that your CPU is in the same performance profile, and so on. Lastly, after you have collected your results, you need to process them with the appropriate statistical tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (assuming a Linux system). You can not only use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) but also some time functions (e.g. [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), etc...) inside the program.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867084/841108).

Look also into [gprof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html), [perf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html), [oprofile(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/oprofile.1.html). You may want to [invoke the GCC compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) specifically (e.g. `gcc -pg`  for `gprof`) for [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) and/or [benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)), which has some overhead.

Comment: Specifically on Linux, `perf stat -d ./a.out` will print some interesting performance counters (CPU microseconds, wall-clock microseconds, branch misses, cache misses, TLB misses, and core clock cycles (not the same thing as RDTSC / wall-clock time because of turbo / frequency scaling).  There's also a "record" mode to associate counts with instructions, but `stat` is good for microbenchmarks (whole program = one loop).  [`ocperf.py` is a nice wrapper for `perf`](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) which adds symbolic names for counters like `uops_issued.any`.

Answer (score 4):

The `time` command will measure the runtime of a given program.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

Comment: Your answer helped me find the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006596/is-the-unix-time-command-accurate-enough-for-benchmarks). It seems that `time` is good. However, it seems that `perf stat` might be better